# How to calculate distance between two regions from bed like dataframe in R?

Tags: r, genomics, bed, dataframe

I'm wondering how can I calculate the distance between two regions from the bed (`chr`, `start`, `end`) alike dataframe in R. Precisely, I want to subtract `end` of r from `start` of r+1 (r=row). Also, the calculation will repeat similarly for each chromosome.

```r
head(G3_dat[1:3])

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  chrom   start     end
  <chr>   <int>   <int>
1 chr1  1330426 1330628
2 chr1  2017424 2017750
3 chr1  2017424 2017750
4 chr1  2018462 2018871
5 chr1  3899411 3899468
6 chr1  4653431 4653724
```

The expected outcome would be,

```r
head(G3_dat[1:4])

    # A tibble: 6 × 4
      chrom   start     end     dis
      <chr>   <int>   <int>     <int>
    1 chr1  1330426 1330628
    2 chr1  2017424 2017750     686796
    3 chr1  2017424 2017750       -326
    4 chr1  2018462 2018871        712
    5 chr1  3899411 3899468    1880540
    6 chr1  4653431 4653724     753963
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two functions in the tidyverse suite (specifically `dplyr`) called `lead` and `lag` that allow calculations like this to be done:

```r
library(tidyverse)
G3_dat %>%
   group_by(chrom) %>%
   arrange(start) %>%
   mutate(dis = start - lag(end))
```

I'm not sure if I've got the lead/lag function correct there (I've updated it based on a suggestion from @ram-rs), but it doesn't take too long to play round with all the combinations to get the right one.

FWIW, `%>%` (or `|>` now in native R) is a "pipe" operator that means "take the result of the last function and feed it into the first argument of the next function". It is used extensively in `tidyverse` scripts. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633022/what-are-the-differences-between-rs-native-pipe-and-the-magrittr-pipe).